# can someone explain IOSTAT ouput?

Tags: linux, iostat

i'am having IBM server with Redhat 5 ElsmP connected to the IBM Storage over iSCSI (in sdb ) can someone explain this output from iostat command

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          12.79    0.01    4.53   72.22    0.00   10.45

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              95.63        48.88       240.95  485589164 2393706728
sdb              29.20       350.49       402.08 3481983365 3994494696
```

move large file to sdb very slowly,it seem normaly?

Comment: thks Kyle for editing i'm beginer :) i'am verry appreciate that :)

Answer (score 6):

The following articles will give you a better idea about iostat. I always use **iostat -x** .

http://mituzas.lt/2009/03/11/iostat/

http://www.igvita.com/2009/06/23/measuring-optimizing-io-performance/

Comment: Good example why "read the docs" is rarely an acceptable answer. Very little explained in those links.
For example: What is TPS?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have 72.22% iowait(time spent by a process while waiting for disk I/O to complete) which is likely why the file move is slow.

Comment: sdb mounted to IBM external Storage over iscsi and we have cronjob to move file from sda to sdb

Comment: You need to look at the IBM external storage stats. That's where the bottleneck appears to be.